# Using OleDB to UPDATE an excel sheet. How can I solve the Operation must use an updatable query error?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Im using OLeDB to Update an excel sheet, however I am stuck on the error : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Operation must use an updateable query.
Heres the code:

```
try
                {
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                    string sql = null;
                    conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + productionMasterPath +
                                   ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes\"");
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Update [salad order$] set @store = @amount where 'SALAD MASTER' = '@salad'";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@store", store);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", int.Parse(item.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salad", item.Key);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
```

My excel file is not set to read only, I have added the user NETWORK SERVICE to Full control privileges on the folder containing the spreadsheet. Is this an issue with my query, my spreadsheet or permissions on my folder?

Comment: Typically, you should use brackets: `[SALAD MASTER]` and don't put quotes around parameters: change `'@salad'` to `@salad`.  Don't know if that solves the issues or not.

Comment: You could try adding `ReadOnly=False` to the connectionstring

Comment: If I remove the quotes from my '@salad' param I get the error "No value given for one or more required parameter" I think this is because many of the salad names have a space in them.

Comment: Adding 'ReadOnly=False' does not seem to have any effect.